# Problems installing the expo-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, expo

I've been trying for the past few hours to install the expo-cli. Half way through installation I keep getting this error:

```
tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.10.0 (sha512-XXX) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
```

After a really long time it crashes without expo-cli being installed.

I thought it could be a problem with Node.js. So I reinstalled **Node.js** and deleted every npm folder I could find. Furthermore cleared the cache with:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Nothing works... Anybody has an idea why I keep getting this error?

Comment: this works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/60699739/4539729

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a common windows issue. Have you tried version 3.7.1?

```
npm i -g expo-cli@3.7.1
```

Otherwise try to install the linux subsystem and use the linux bash.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it with this specific version of expo-cli. But I still get the same error :(